# Coefficient of Quartile Variation in R

Tags: r, quartile

I am trying to calculate the coefficient of quartile variation in R for every 3 consecutive measurements.

```
cqv_versatile(
    Q, 
    na.rm = TRUE, 
    digits = 3)
```

```
    Q
    49
    44
    34
    33
    37
    48
    20
    48
    37
    42
    44
    35
    40
```

Does someone knows how to calculate the `cqv_versatile` with this consecutive interval?

Comment: You want to estimate quartiles from 3 data points? Are you sure?

Comment: I want to estimate the (Quartil 3 - Quartil 1)/ (Quartil 3 - Quartil1) for 3 consecutive rows (example: 49,44,34), in order to analyze the material dispersion.  My data is non-normal, that is why I choose coefficient of quartile varitions, than i dont need to transformate the data.

Comment: I understand, I am asking if you really want to estimate quartiles from three rows? That's a pathetic amount of data, there will be a lot of extrapolation in the estimates.

Comment: I see, in the question did not have the complete data.  I have 68 rows for each group of data that I was thinking in apply the coefficient of quartile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using base R, change the `hst` variable to your desired sublength (just to be clear, the first coefficient is estimated based on  values with indices 1,2,3; the second coefficient is estimated based on values with indices 4,5,6)

```
Q=as.numeric(read.table(text="49 44 34 33 37 48 20 48 37 42 44 35 40"))

hst=3

sapply(seq(1,length(Q),hst),function(x){
  tmp=x:(pmin(x+hst-1,length(Q)))
  q1=quantile(Q[tmp],0.25)
  q3=quantile(Q[tmp],0.75)
  as.numeric((q3-q1)/(q3+q1))
})

[1] 0.08771930 0.09677419 0.19718310 0.05521472 0.00000000
```

As mentioned in the comments, you should really use more data to when estimating the  coefficient.

If you want to estimate based on a rolling window, so indices 1,2,3 -> 2,3,4 -> ... just replace `seq(1,length(Q),hst)` with `seq(1,length(Q),1)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to see how the estimating coefficient will work in my data, otherwise, I will try another analysis to analyze the dispersion of the material.

Comment: @JacquelineSantos If this answered your question consider accepting this answer to close the matter.